# Add text from a text field to an array (as an integer)

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'd like to have the user input their mark into a text field, I'd then like to have a button (submit) add that mark to an array of other marks.

```
List <Integer[]> markBook = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> nameBook = new ArrayList<>();
int getMark;
this.getMark = Integer.parseInt(markField.getText());
markBook.add(markField.getText());`
```

Not sure if I need the Integer.parseInt because that was for when I was trying to convert my text to an int before adding it to the array. And for reference the markBook.add... is inside an action listener for the submit button.

Comment: `markBook.add(new Integer[]{getMark});` ...?

Comment: If they are adding only one mark, do you mean to have a `List<Integer>`? Also `Integer.valueOf(String)` would be more efficient here so that you don't incur the boxing cost.

Comment: MadProgrammer the solution you suggested does not work and give me the error "cannot find symbol --> symbol add(Integer[]) location variable markBook of type int[]

Comment: mvd 13 the reason I use an array is because I need to have an entire class input their marks then have averages and highest lowest marks shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code work for this scenario :

```
List<Integer> markBook = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> nameBook = new ArrayList<>();
int getMark;
try {
  getMark = Integer.valueOf(markField.getText());
}catch(Exception ex) {
  getMark = 0; //default value if you don't want to give 
               //default the just display error message 
}
markBook.add(getMark);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong type.

The following gives you a list *of an array of integers*. So essentially you have an array of arrays (2D array) here.

`List<Integer[]> markBook = new ArrayList<>();`

On the other hand, this one creates a list of *integers*, which is what I think you want.

`List<Integer> markBook = new ArrayList<>();`

Then, you can take the `String` of text that should be a number, parse it using `Integer.parseInt()`, and then add it to the list.

So, your code should look something like the following (of course doing your own error checking and whatnot):

```
List<Integer> markBook = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> nameBook = new ArrayList<>();
int getMark = Integer.parseInt(markField.getText());
markBook.add(getMark);
```